# How can I delete from my smartphone the images downloaded by Google Chrome from the internet, which I can't find anywhere?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, google, downloading, images

I have a A3 Umidigi smartphone, Android 9. I downloaded the images by Google Chrome (search images engine), and I can't find them in any folder (included Download, Pictures or DCIM), but I can see and use them as backgrounds (actually I use as background one of these downloaded, invisible images). I searched them using the App "Total Commander" (and other similar), and I connected the smartphone to the desktop by usb cable, but I couldn't find them. Google Chrome has access to the drive. Now, if I download another picture, Chrome asks me where to save it, but I have a dozen images I can't find.

[Download folder (without the downloaded pictures).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yce9Q.jpg)

[Download options in Google Chrome (without the pictures).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVtZd.jpg)

["Background" selector: I can see and select the pictures (even offline). By the way I can't find any App named Background or whatsoever.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRVzQ.jpg)

[Root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BESmA.png)

[Root/data/data folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX5kh.png)

[Root/system folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUE57.png)

[data/com.android.chrome/files/Download folder (empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA6Ba.png)

Comment: Did you look for it in the **Downloads** option in chrome? (not the "system download' app)

Comment: Wallpaper once set is saved to `/data/system/users/<User_Id>/`.

Comment: I looked for in the Download option in Chrome, but there aren't. I can't find the exact folder Android\data\system, or data\system, but only Android\data\... (with many subfolders such as ...\com.google.android.apps.docs).

Comment: I added three screenshots in the question: the Download folder, the Download option in Chrome, and the Pictures in the background application. Only in the latter I can find the pictures.

Comment: @Mishima `/data/system` is in the root folder. This is not the same as the `Android/data` folder you access from your internal storage.

Comment: What is the download location shown in Chrome?

Comment: I noticed the "root", now. I have the folders root\data and root\system but not root/data/system.
In root\data there is the folder root/data/data/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander
In root\system there is a \usr folder (not user), with the following subfolders: hyphen-data, icu, idc, jeychars, keylayout, share, srec.

Comment: The download location shown in Chrome is Download/storage/emulated/0/Download, but I can't find the files there (it's before the root folder). On Google Chrome now I have the option Ask where to save files on.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder `/data/data/com.android.chrome` and its subfolders, would be the place to look. You will need superuser permission to be able to access this folder. In Total Commander start File System Root.

For example `/data/data/com.android.chrome/cache/image_cache` Has picture files. Actually all the files in there are pics even though they have no extension.

Comment: I found the folder Root/data/data/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander (with an empty /files folder inside), but not Root/data/data/com.android.chrome.
There is the folder storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download, which is empty.
Maybe I have no permissions...

Comment: Is your devic rooted? If not that would be why you see an empty folder. Without root permission you can't access inside that folder.

Comment: I don't know if the smartphone is rooted. In case, how can I check and have permission to access the folder?

Comment: If you didn't root it it's probably not rooted. There is an app on google play that checks if your device is rooted. [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en_US&gl=US)

Comment: I installed the App, and "Root access is not properly installed on this device".